# How does Webpack determine what to include in its bundle?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Assume I have a project with the following structure

```
/app
|_webpack.config.js
|_package.json
|_/npm_modules
| |_...
|_/client
  |_/misc
  | |_...
  |_/components
  | |_...
  |_index.jsx
```

and `webpack.config.js` contains this

```
entry: ["./client/index.jsx"]
```

and `index.jsx` loads all components like this

```
var components = [];
var componentPaths = require.context("./components", false);
componentPaths.keys().forEach(function(path)  {
    components.push(componentPaths(path));
});
```

What files will be bundled into the resulting bundle.js?
Will it just be `/app/client/index.jsx` and all files in the `/app/client/components` directory?
Or will the entire `/app/client` directory be bundled (including everything under `/app/client/misc`)?
Or will the entire `/app` directory be bundled (including everything under `/app/npm_modules`)?

I've been trying to figure this out based on the Webpack docs, but they are inadequate. If you know the answer, including a reference to where you found the information would be very helpful.

I'm asking because I want to set up a project that has multiple entry points where the resulting bundle.js files only include what is necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you use `import` or `require`. If a file is not imported or required it will not be included in the bundle.

[It's explained here.](http://webpack.github.io/docs/what-is-webpack.html)

Note: `import` is an ES6 feature and you'd need Babel to use it across most browsers.

Comment: So you are saying that files under the `/app/client/misc` will not be included? Does webpack search for every require and import statement in a file and determine dependencies that way?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you don't import or require a file it will not be bundled by Webpack. You can of course write a node script to copy those files to your dev or production folder.

Comment: Also, yes, Webpack will search for every import/require recursively.

Comment: After looking at the documentation a little more, it looks like this is what I was looking for http://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html. By the way, if webpack only requires whatever is specifically referenced recursively from the entry file, then why do people add the `exclude: './npm_modules'` option in their `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: `exclude` is not for excluding files from bundling, it's for excluding certain files from being processed by loaders. Loaders are plugins that transform the code before being bundled. https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders

Comment: Ah ok. It looks like there is an option to exclude from bundling process, which is the `externals` property. I think it's very interesting how webpack is able to deduce what modules to bundle based on require statements, even when the require statement has an expression inside of it.